# Haskell laziness question with head function

Tags: haskell

Info:

From Docs and tutorials it says: "Haskell is lazy" by default.

They don't explain the details about it, and i wonder.

Now I know that if I write:

```
filter odd [1, 2, 3]
```

It will not filter the results until they are showed or used in expression.

I have a couple of questions about this:

---

Is the `head` function lazy?

If not why is it not lazy?

If it is lazy, how does the Haskell compiler know when to execute the function?

I give you an example:

```
f a b = head a + head b

f [2, 3] [4, 5]
```

In this case from my perspective head will **NOT** return 2 + 4.

It will return some type or function that will be executed later when needed. (correct me if i mistaken somewhere).

So my suggestion is that when Haskell see some operation like '+' it calculates the result.

But it gets more complicated because for Integers i suppose if i write `3 + 5` it can be lazy expression as well.

I doubt there are list with functions when the lazy expression starts calculating because it will be hard to write all the variations.

And last:

```
f head [1, 2]
```

Lets say in `f` function I print the type of the variable passed.

Now how Haskell will know if the Int 1 should be passed or the lazy expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the `head` function lazy?

Yes, Haskell is lazily evaluated by default.

> If it is lazy, how does the Haskell compiler know when to execute the function?

The function will be evaluated when the value is needed - which, as far as I understand, ultimately happens when you involve `IO` in some way.

> In this case from my perspective head will NOT return 2 + 4.

Correct, the return 'value' is a so-called **thunk**, which is another name for an expression not yet evaluated. What's the expression? It's `head a + head b`.

The main exception from the rule of lazy evaluation is `IO`, which is eagerly evaluated. So if you want to, say, *print* the result of calling `f [2, 3] [4, 5]`, then enough of the expression gets evaluated to produce a result to print.

There are ways to force evaluation earlier, if required, e.g. by using `seq`. This can sometimes be important, because those thunks can get big.

Comment: Thanks, this means even if statements are lazy, because if compare functions are lazy then ifs' should be lazy too, right?

Comment: Assuming the function f returns a normal number (like an Int) it will not in fact returns 6.  It will NOT, repeat NOT, return a thunk. How does this rhyme with Haskell being lazy (actually, non-strict) you ask?  Well, the thing is that laziness will ensure that f isn’t called until you need the value. So returning a thunk would be pointless, since it would have to be forced at once.

Comment: @user2693928 As I'm sure you'll discover as people start to pile comments on my answer, the actual implementation of how GHC does all of this is complicated. As I understand it, though, then comparisons and branching are also lazily evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, flaged the answer as correct, just final clarification if its possible. If it passes some lazy type in some function that takes Int how is that possible. It accept Int but I pass LazyType(whatever the implementation is in Haskell)

Comment: @user2693928 I don't understand what you mean. If a function takes `Int` as an argument, you can't pass `LazyType` as an argument instead. That wouldn't compile.

Comment: because in some recursive function it takes first argument as Int but they pass head(xs) or similar. How come the variable is both Int and LazyObject

Comment: I mean this: 3 `mod` 3 = 0, head([3,4]) `mod` 3 also eq 0. How mod function takes both Int and LazyObject ?

Comment: @user2693928 `mod` is also lazy ;)

Comment: O, forgot everything is lazy thank :) Good luck debugging complicated algorithm :)

Comment: @user2693928 Laziness is not something that is distinguished at the type level. I don't see how this would make things more complicated to debug, since changing something from lazy to strict does not change the result of something (excluding bottom)...

Comment: For your "ultimately" sentence, we can get more precise: `main`, and only `main`, drives all evaluation. (Simply involving IO is not enough. `x = print (head []); main = return ()` will not blow up, even though `print (head [])` is an IO action that would blow up if it were actually included in the execution of `main`.)

Answer (score 4):

I think there is some confusion here because the term "lazy" is sometimes used in two different contexts.

- lazy semantics (as opposed to eager semantics)
- lazy function (which should actually be called non-strict function)

About lazy vs eager semantics: consider this expression

```
(\x -> 42) (error "urk!")
```

when the above is evaluated, what is the result?

According to *eager* semantics, we evaluate the argument before calling the function. The result will be a runtime error.

According to lazy semantics, we call the function immediately. This process can be understood both operationally and denotationally as follows.

Operationally, it is passed a *thunk*, an object which describes the not-yet-evaluated argument, and which will be "forced" (evaluated) whenever the argument `x` is needed. We can pretend that `x` points to the unevaluated expression `error "urk!"`, which will be evaluated when `x` is demanded.

Denotationally, we use a mathematical trick: we denote the error with a special value called "bottom", and say that `error "urk!"` has such bottom value.
Then, we simply pretend that this exceptional value can be passed around. In the function call above, `x` will be bound to "bottom", as if it were a normal value. This is arguably simpler because we do not need to focus on how the expressions are evaluated, but only on how the bottom is propagated.

More precisely, we let "bottom" represent both runtime errors and non-termination (infinite recursion), both of which let a program get away with returning an actual result.

For instance, we have that `if bottom then .. else ..` will always yield bottom. Similarly for `bottom + 4`, which is bottom. Again, `case bottom of SomeConstructor -> ...; ...` is bottom (well, except for `newtypes`, but let's ignore this). Instead `f bottom` may or may not be bottom according to what `f` does: if it needs the argument, the result will be bottom.

About lazy (non-strict) functions. A function `f` is sometimes said to be "lazy" (or, more properly, non-strict) iff `f bottom` is not bottom.

For instance:

```
f x = x+1  -- strict / non lazy
f x = 5    -- non strict / lazy
head xs = case xs of   -- strict / non lazy
   [] -> error "head: empty list"
   (x:xs) -> x
g x = (x,True)   -- non strict / lazy
```

So, since `head bottom` is `case bottom of ...` which is bottom, `head` is not lazy. Operationally, since `head` demands its argument before producing its result, it is strict / non lazy.

About `g`: a main feature of lazy semantics is that `data` constructors like the pair constructor `(,)` are intrinsically lazy. That is `(bottom, 4)` is not the same as bottom: this makes it possible to have `snd (bottom, 4) = 4` even if the first pair component is an "error" value.

So, `g bottom = (bottom, True)` is not bottom, and we could apply `snd` to extract `True` without triggering the error.